# Find a geographic concentration of values?

Tags: postgis

I have a database table (PostGIS/Postgres) of points (dozens to thousands), each of which have a `Value` and a `Position` (latitude/longitude in a `geography` datatype).

I am trying to figure out whether I have too much `Value` concentrated in any one place.

More specifically, I am trying to find an efficient approach to figure out if any circle of radius `r`, encloses a total summed `Value` over a threshold `MAX_ACCEPTABLE_VALUE_IN_CIRCLE`.

This can be done in PostGIS SQL or the data can be pulled and an algorithm run locally in Python, it doesn't really matter.

Are there any preexisting approaches or optimizations that might help?

Answer (score 2):

One of the best visual descriptions (see below) of different clustering algorithms can be found on the [scikit-learn clustering](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/cluster/plot_cluster_comparison.html) page. This also answers one part of your question, can this be done in Python.

[image]

Postgres also provides methods for [DBScan](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_ClusterDBSCAN.html), [ClusterWithin](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_ClusterWithin.html) and [KMeans](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_ClusterKMeans.html).

These algorithms differ in various ways, such as whether the clusters are built based on some threshold distance between each point (DBScan, ClusterWithin) or a threshold distance to a cluster centre (K Means) and whether you have to provide a distance or the number of clusters as an input.

From the description of your problem it sounds like you need some version of KMeans, as you are concerned with densities in a specific area, rather than how many things are x-distance apart -- in DBScan, for example, you could have various snake-like clusters, which would give you no notion of regional density. The problem with KMeans is that is is not deterministic -- it requires that you input the number of clusters and each iteration will produce a different result.

One possibility is to run it multiple times with different numbers of clusters, until the average cluster dispersion (in terms of distance from the centroid) approaches your radius above. Averaging over several iterations, dense areas should become apparent.

Based on a comment by [thigamabob](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/93656/thingumabob), another completely different approach might be to use hexbins. There is a [Postgres implementation](https://github.com/minus34/postgis-scripts/tree/master/hex-grid), which I have tested and it works really well. Hexbins are useful because they evenly tile an area (and are closeish to circles) and avoid analysis based on arbitrary political or administrative areas. It would seem to fit well with your notion of number of points within a radius r, although, again, the results will be dependent on the start point of the tiling. I have run this with crime statistics with different sized hexagons and different starting points, with interesting and fairly stable results. There is even a [hexagon layer using webGL from Uber's deckgl](https://uber.github.io/deck.gl/#/documentation/layer-catalog/hexagon-layer) that gives great visualizations, though this might be getting a bit removed from what you originally asked.

Comment: well, your multiple iterations approach with kmeans has something to it. but the issue in general seems to be that the desired analysis doesn't rely on any *spatial cluster* distribution at all, since it's interest lies in the concentration of *summed up values* over *any* circle of specified radius. I come to think that a circular moving window would be best suited, sequentially covering the whole study area...

Comment: @ThingumaBob. Indeed, which is why I suggested running KMeans multiple times, with different cluster numbers, until they converged. However, you have given me another idea based on hexagons.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:**
*Completely misunderstood the question.*
I think you are looking for cluster analysis, and I guess you could use [ST_ClusterDBSCAN](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_ClusterDBSCAN.html) for that. Not sure though if the value dependency might make that unfit for your task.

<s>Try this:</s>

```
WITH
    circles AS (
        SELECT <uid> AS id,
               <center> AS geom,
               <radius> AS radius    --optional, only if each cirlce has an individual radius, see 2nd comment below
        FROM <your_circle_table>
    )

SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT circles.id,
           sum(points.Value) AS sum
    FROM <your_points_table> AS points,
         circles
    WHERE ST_DWithin(
              points.Position,
              circles.geom,          -- add '::geography' if your circle table has geometry type
              circles.radius         -- replace with number if you have a constant radius for all circles
          )
    GROUP BY circles.id
) AS query
WHERE query.sum > MAX_VALUE_IN_CIRCLE
```

This assumes that you have more than one circle in a table `<your_circle_table>` with unique ids in column `<uid>`, defined by their center coordinates in column `<center>`.

Comment: Thanks! But I think my problem statement was unclear -- I don't know/care where the circle is centered, I am looking to know if I have a high concentration of `Value` anywhere.  I will try to restate the issue.

Comment: @ScottStafford haha, damn...didn´t get that. you are looking for a cluster analysis and you probably want the [ST_ClusterDBSCAN](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_ClusterDBSCAN.html) function.

Comment: Ya, sorry, and I really appreciate it -- will look into those.

Comment: Actually, it sounds like KMeans might be more appropriate to a regional density estimate.